# Domain of a maximal solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f, g \colon \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be continuous functions with $f (x) \geq g (x)> 0$ for all $x$.

Show that if

$x'= f (x)$,  $x (0) = 0$,

has some definite solution over all $\mathbb{R}$, so

$y '= g (y)$,  $y (0) = 0$

also has a definite solution over all $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I tried to go absurd and just managed to prove that x (t) less than or equal to y (t) but I'm not sure if it's right because I don't know if x (t) is a maximal solution.

Comment: I also tried to see if changing the variable s -> x (s) and s -> y (s) helped something but doesn’t move